# TSlint and React: How to enforce styles at bottom before export default?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, tslint, prettier

I'm building a React Native app with TypeScript. I'm currently configuring my TSLint file.

Is there a way to enforce styles in the same document to be at the bottom of the file (before the exports)?

E.g. `MyComponent.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-navigation";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});

export class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Text>This screen is my component.</Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Should throw an error, whereas:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';

export class MyComponent extends Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Text>This screen is my component.</Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});

export default MyComponent;
```

should pass?

Comment: You will have to create your own rule for this I'm almost 100% sure.

Comment: Oh wow, I've never done that. Guess I'm gonna look into how to do that. Thank you @Baruch